# How can I disable the clipboard prompt in excel vba when I close the workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, clipboard

So I'm working with multiple workbooks from which I copy all the data from Sheet1 from each one into their respective sheet on the master workbook. After I do that, I have the multiple workbooks encoded to close. However, an annoying prompt asking if I want to keep the copied data on clipboard consistently pops up and I want to either have it not pop up or when it does, I want "No" to be automatically chosen.

I know there's a similar question that's been asked but it hasn't worked for me and I'm thinking it's because I have a rectangular area of data instead of just a column? I really new at vba but I tried messing around with the code in [Disable clipboard prompt in Excel VBA on workbook close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163265/disable-clipboard-prompt-in-excel-vba-on-workbook-close) but I've had no luck.

Here's my original code:

```
Sub CFM56copydata()
Dim wbk As Workbook
'The workbook is opened using the text from a textbox in a userform i.e:
strFirstFile = Userform1.dog.Text
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
End With
Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook
wbk2.Sheets("dog").Range("A1").Insert
wbk.Close
End Sub
```

and here's how I tried to tweak it so I avoided using the clipbaord at all. (Didn't work, gives me a debug error on line 12)

```
Sub fix()
Dim wbk As Workbook
strFirstFile = Userform1.CFM56path.Text
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook
Dim rSrc As Range
Dim rDst As Range
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Set rSrc = Selection
Set rDst = wbk2.Sheets("dog").Cells("A1").Resize(rSrc.Rows.Count, rSrc.Columns.Count)
rDst = rSrc
wbk.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the clipboard prompt is the problem, just empty it after your done pasting.

```
wbk2.Sheets("dog").Range("A1").Insert
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbk.Close
```

Comment: Thanks! These were both great suggestions and they both worked! I ended up using the code to empty the clipboard because  it was one less line

Comment: To be clear, this does not empty the clipboard. It only removes the "dancing ants" around the copied area. If you copy enough data, you may still get the message.

Answer (score 5):

It should work if you change your `wbk.Close` statement to:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbk.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Thanks! These were both great suggestions and they both worked! I ended up using the code to empty the clipboard because  it was one less line